# Group items in a list based on two properties using LINQ MVC

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am working on a API integration.
I have a model like this

```
public class Flight
{
    public string Origin{ get; set; }
    public string Destination{ get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber{ get; set; }
    public string Provider{ get; set; }
}
```

And a list of flight like this

```
 List<Flight> Flight= new List<Flight>();
```

Lets assume these are the data

```
Flight:
{
    Segment1: { Origin= CMB , Destination=MAA , FlightNumber= 123, Provider= p}
    Segment2: { Origin= MAA, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 543, Provider= p }
    Segment3: { Origin= MAA, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 320, Provider= p}
    Segment4: { Origin= CMB, Destination= BOM, FlightNumber= 644, Provider= p}
    Segment5: { Origin= BOM, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
    Segment6: { Origin= CMB, Destination= KMG, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
    Segment7: { Origin= KMG, Destination= PEK, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
    Segment8: { Origin= PEK, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
}
```

**SearchingOrigin = "CMB"**

**SearchingDestination = "DEL"**

I need to group these items as displayed below

```
Transit_segmentList---->[0]---->[0]{ Origin= CMB , Destination=MAA , FlightNumber= 123, Provider= p}
                    |           [1]{ Origin= MAA, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 543, Provider= p }
                    |           [2]{ Origin= MAA, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 320, Provider= p}
                    |
                    --->[1]---->[0]{ Origin= CMB, Destination= BOM, FlightNumber= 644, Provider= p}
                    |           [1]{ Origin= BOM, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
                    |
                    --->[2]---->[0]{ Origin= CMB, Destination= KMG, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
                                [1]{ Origin= KMG, Destination= PEK, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
                                [2]{ Origin= PEK, Destination= DEL, FlightNumber= 233, Provider= p}
```

My main origin is CMB and Main destination is DEL. I want to group them like this

1)Actually segment 1 , 2, 3 are flight details of a single trip. The plane stops at **MAA** on the way to **DEL**.Segment 3 is an alternate segment to segment 2.
So I want to take those 3 segments to one list item(**Transit_segmentList**).

2)Same like above.Flight is flying From CMB to DEL.It stops at BOM. But this is a single trip.I want to get it to the **Transit_segmentList** as the second trip.

3) segment 6,7,8 are also parts of a same trip. Have to sort them as the above diagram

Comment: Shouldn't `List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();` be `List<Flight> Flights= new List<Flight>();` instead ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please do not ask for people to write the code for you

Comment: "*Segment 3 is an alternate segment to segment 3*" typo here. Also, to solve your problem you might want to search for **graph theory** and **search algorithms** such as Dijkstra or A*, or many others as this is what it is about. As per your `Transit_segmentList[2]`, you seek not only for one-junction travels, but n-junctions travels

Comment: Thank you Green.I corrected the errors.I already tried linq queries and write for loops. Couldn't get it done

Comment: Yes i am searching n-junction travels too. Actually I am getting a huge object list as a result  and this is just a small piece of it.. I have done most of the things but i am stuck with this matter

Comment: How would you handle if option [2] had two alternate paths for the second and third flights?

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of extension methods, you can generate all combinations of flights and filter them to the ones desired, then combine them together on the first flight.

Here are the extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T first) {
    yield return first;
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

Then you just generate the combinations and filter:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(1, Flights.Length)
                    .SelectMany(k => Flights.Combinations(k))
                    .Where(fs => fs.Count() == 1 || fs.Where(f1 => fs.Any(f2 => f1.Destination == f2.Origin)).Count() == fs.Count() - 1)
                    .Where(fs => fs.Any(f => f.Origin == SearchingOrigin) && fs.Any(f => f.Destination == SearchingDestination))
                    .GroupBy(fs => fs.Where(f => f.Origin == SearchingOrigin).First())
                    .Select(fsg => fsg.Key.AsSingleton().Concat(fsg.SelectMany(fs => fs.Except(fsg.Key.AsSingleton()))).ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to build a *graph* out of segments and *traverse* all combinations/paths/itineraries.

Another approach, to a certain degree similar to the first one, would be to iterate over the segments, `.Push` each of them to a `Stack`, find next destinations, and *recurse*, making sure the current segment is `.Pop` out of the stack once there are no more associated destinations to evaluate (see bellow).

```
public class Segment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Flight { get; set; }
}

public class Analyzer
{
    public Analyzer(IEnumerable<Segment> segments)
    {
        Segments = segments;
    }

    protected IEnumerable<Segment> Segments { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Segment>> Process(IEnumerable<Segment> origins = null, Stack<Segment> current = null)
    {
        if (origins == null)
            origins = Segments;
        if (current == null)
            current = new Stack<Segment>();

        foreach (var origin in origins)
        {
            current.Push(origin);

            var destinations = Segments.Where(p => p.Origin == origin.Destination);
            if (destinations.Any())
            {
                foreach (var child in Process(destinations, current))
                {
                    yield return child;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                yield return current.Reverse().ToList();
            }

            current.Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

this will give you all the itinerary (group of segments) combinations

```
var itineraries = new Analyzer(segments).Process();
```

[image: itineraries]

but you mention that you want them grouped by initial flight as there might be many variants of the same itinerary, which makes total sense

```
var query = from itinerary in itineraries
            let first = itinerary.First()
            let last = itinerary.Last()
            where trip.Origin == first.Origin
                && trip.Destination == last.Destination
            group itinerary by first.Flight into groupings
            select groupings
                .SelectMany(p => p)
                .Distinct();
```

and this should give you the expected results

[image: results]

Note: Of course, there is a cost for iterating this way and yielding while doing recursion, and might have some performance penalties if the graph is very deep, but when talking about flight segments, the less the merrier :)

Comment: check gist for an overview for the entire solution https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/579b922c77b2818d3e3f1ff5c468cae8#file-stack-48317842-cs